# Get http with dynamic Url using Retrofit library

Tags: android, retrofit

i want get rss code from a url with retrofit and if i enter url staticly in the Get annotation everything is ok but with dynamic url i get a error.

my interface service :

```
public interface AllNewsService {

    @GET("/{newsGroup}")
    void getRss( @Path("newsGroup") String nGroup ,  Callback<AllNewsRss> callback);

}
```

and  calling getRss method :

```
  mClient.get().getRss("allnews" ,new Callback<AllNewsRss>() {
        @Override
        public void success(AllNewsRss allNewsRss, Response response) {

            Log.d(TAG,allNewsRss.getNews().get(0).getTitle());

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Log.d(TAG,error.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

i get below error :

```
 retrofit.RetrofitError: AllNewsService.getRss: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tested your code and this is working for me (with 1.9.0). Also I don't see anything wrong in your interface declaration.

Which Retrofit version are you currently using?

Also do you have Proguard configured? There seems to cause some issues with Retrofit which may yield your error.

Comment: thank you  . my retrofit version is 1.9.0  . how disable Progruard?  i deleted it from gradle file .

Comment: Check this link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide in the Running Proguard section